# Assigning numbers to mysql rows depending on their other variables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So I have 2 tables in MYSQL which look like this:

```
person(ID, name, division, subdivision, number)
label(ID, divsion, subdivision, ordernum)
```

**person table**

Persons are inputed via form, where name, division and subdivision are submitted. The ID column is autoincremented, and I'll get to the number column shortly.

**label table**

The labels are already inputed and can't be modified. There are different types of groups, and inside those divisions, 5 subgdivisions for each (to make it short, lets say car 1/2/3/4/5, plane 1/2/3/4/5, and so on).
Each of these rows have an order number assigned, starting from one.

My objective is to, once all persons are input, order them by the ordernum comparing their group and subgroup data (they can of course be repeated, just one beneath the other) and after this, assign them a number (which is where the number column comes in).

Once the persons are in order by ordernum, I want the numbers to be assigned like this:

The number of persons have to be a multiple of 5. Lets say for the sake of this example, there are 20 persons. I would want the numbers to be assigned like this:

1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4

Before I was doing this all with javascript, but I encountered too many problems and the number wasn't recorded in the DB, so I wanted to ask if something like this was possible via PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's very possible in PHP - presumably your javascript implementation sent information to PHP anyway. What have you tried so far? `Once the persons are in order` - you probably want to start with this, i.e. an SQL query which returns all the people in order.

Comment: Group and order are both reserved words, making them less than ideal column names. Rotten luck really because of the 6m words in the English language only approximately 250 of them are reserved.

Comment: Let me change the reserved words issue first ^^'

Comment: So yes, my javascript implementation works fine and sends the persons data into the DB with PHP.
Im quite new to SQL, so Im not sure what queries to run and how to run them to achieve my objective